# How does third party applications (like DISA) show WhatsApp messages while it's end-to-end encrypted?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, messaging, whatsapp, end-to-end

[WhatsApp Disa Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sny3j.jpg)

I have a doubt on WhatsApp's end to end encryption. If it is really ends to end encrypted messenger, how come third-party application can decrypt messages.

What kind of plugin does WhatsApp offer to such third party apps if there is end to end encryption?

Comment: What do you mean by third party?! MITM?

Comment: There is one messenger is available on android market, not sure about apple, called [DISA](http://disa.im/). By installing this third-party app I can use my WhatsApp without official app.

Comment: I dont see a problem here. Its either using something like whatsapp protocol (if any exists, not use) and its still encrypting, or its something like phishing scam or fake app.

Comment: I have used this app, its works exactly like whatsapp, my question is if it is end to end encryption how they are able to decrypt whatsapp messages.